# Load URL into iframe and find values of the HTML that was just loaded - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a URL into an iframe by doing the following jquery code. The problem is that when I try to find a  element of the iframe that was just loaded, it always returns the content that was loaded in the previous click. And the first click is always null. Can someone help me to get around this? Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Popup').click(function() {

        $('#myiframe')
                .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
                .attr('frameborder', '0')

        return false;
    });
    alert($('#myiframe').contents().find('.name').html())
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the the fetched URL to load into the iframe before you can fetch contents from it. You can use the the [jquery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to do this. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.Popup').click(function() {

        $('#myiframe')
                .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
                .attr('frameborder', '0')
                .load(function() {
                     alert($(this).contents().find('.name').html())
                })

        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason is that you are alerting after *registering the onclick event handle*. What you should be doing is this, I guess:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Popup').click(function() {

        $('#myiframe')
                .attr('src', $(this).attr('href'))
                .attr('frameborder', '0');
        $($("#myIframe").get(0).contentDocument).ready(function() {
            alert($('#myiframe').contents().find('.name').html())
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to wait for the iFrame to load before the alert goes off. You can use the `load` function for that.

```
$("#myiframe").load(function() {
    alert("iFrame has loaded. You can now get content out of it");
});
```